# Binary Tree : Advantages of pre-order ,post-order traversals in Binary Tree?

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

Inorder traversal of a Binary Search Tree yields nodes in increasing order. But what advantages do pre order and post order traversals have on any binary tree?

EDIT:What I mean by advantages is : "any situation where applying pre-order or post-order traversal is specifically suited".

Comment: Sometimes you need pre order, sometimes you need post order, sometimes it doesn't matter.. I don't see what you mean by "advantages".

Comment: What I mean by advantages is : "any situation where applying pre-order or post-order traversal is specifically suited".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not all binary trees have numbers in them. You can use a binary tree to represent things that exhibit tree structure, such as *expressions*. For example, `2 * 3 + 4` can be represented as

```
              +
            /   \
           *     4
         /   \
        2     3
```

If you represent an expression like that, the in-order traversal would yield your "normal" infix notation of

```
2 * 3 + 4
```

but a post-order traversal would yield a [*Reverse Polish Notation*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Polish_notation) of the expression:

```
2 3 * 4 +
```

Comment: Can you please also provide a valuable resource on how to convert infix notation to postfix notation using a binary tree .

Comment: @NikunjBanka There is a good answer to [this question on stack overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4589951/335858) that talks about converting expressions to trees. Once the tree is built, all you need to do is a post-order traversal of it to get the same expression in postfix notation.