# Evaluating an arithmetic expression without delimiters

Tags: java, algorithm

I want to create a method that evaluates an arithmetic expression like for example `((2+100)*5)*7` containing no spaces between operands and operators
If there are spaces I would use the split method giving it the `" "` as delimiter.

Can anyone help me find the algorithm to solve this kind of problem?

Comment: For that (like in programming languages), you use tokens (e.g. special characters or braces).

Comment: but I wont get each operand seperately

Answer (score 1):

#### Variant 1:

You can use the javascript engine to evaluate the expression.

private static final ScriptEngine engine = new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByName("JavaScript");

```
public static String eval(String expression){
    if(expression == null){
        return "NULL";
    }
    String js_parsable_expression = expression
            .replaceAll("\\((\\-?\\d+)\\)\\^(\\-?\\d+)", "(Math.pow($1,$2))")
            .replaceAll("(\\d+)\\^(\\-?\\d+)", "Math.pow($1,$2)");
    try{
        return engine.eval(js_parsable_expression).toString();
    }catch(javax.script.ScriptException ex){
        return "NULL";
    }
}
```

Note that you have to convert all `^` to `Math.pow` for powers.

#### Variant 2

You can use the [Shunting-yard alghoritm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm)

Ex:

> Input: 3+4

- Add 3 to the output queue (whenever a number is read it is added to the output)
- Push + (or its ID) onto the operator stack
- Add 4 to the output queue
- After reading the expression pop the operators off the stack and add them to the output.
- In this case there is only one, "+".

> Output: 3 4 +

### My implementation of the algorithm (sorry for the bad naming):

```
private static final TreeMap<Character, Integer> operatorsOrder= new TreeMap<Character, Integer>();
static
{
    operatorsOrder.put('(', 0);
    operatorsOrder.put(')', 0);  
    operatorsOrder.put('+', 1);
    operatorsOrder.put('-', 1);
    operatorsOrder.put('*', 2);
    operatorsOrder.put('/', 2);
    operatorsOrder.put('%', 2);
    operatorsOrder.put('s', 3);
    operatorsOrder.put('l', 3);
}

private void evalButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)                                           
{ 
    final Stack<Character> operatori  = new Stack<Character>();
    final Stack<Double> valori = new Stack<Double>();

    String expresie = exprTf.getText();
    expresie = expresie.replaceAll("sqrt", "s");
    expresie = expresie.replaceAll("ln", "l");

    final StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    final char[] expresieChar = expresie.toCharArray();

    for(int i = 0; i<expresieChar.length; i++)
    {
        char ch = expresieChar[i];
        if (!operatorsOrder.containsKey(ch))
        {
            if(Character.isDigit(ch))
            {
                while (Character.isDigit(ch) || ch == '.')
                {
                    builder.append(ch);
                    if(++i <expresieChar.length)
                        ch = expresieChar[i];
                    else
                        break;
                }
                --i;
                valori.push(Double.parseDouble(builder.toString()));
                builder.delete(0, builder.capacity());
            }
            continue;
        }

        while (true)
        {
            if (operatori.isEmpty() || ch == '(' || (operatorsOrder.get(ch) > operatorsOrder.get(operatori.peek())))
            {
                operatori.push(ch);
                break;
            }

            final char op = operatori.pop();

            if (op == '(')
            {
                if(ch == ')')
                    break;
            }
            else if(op == 's' || op == 'l')
            {
                final double val1 = valori.pop();
                valori.push(eval(op, val1, 0));
            }
            else
            {
                final double val2 = valori.pop();
                final double val1 = valori.pop();
                valori.push(eval(op, val1, val2));
            }
        }
    }

    while (!operatori.isEmpty())
    {
        final char op = operatori.pop();
        if(op == 's' || op == 'l')
        {
            final double val1 = valori.pop();
            valori.push(eval(op, val1, 0));
        }
        else
        {
            final double val2 = valori.pop();
            final double val1 = valori.pop();
            valori.push(eval(op, val1, val2));
        }
    }
    resultLabel.setText(String.valueOf(valori.pop()));
    if(!operatori.isEmpty())
        System.out.println("There are operators left.");
    if(!valori.isEmpty())
        System.out.println("There are operands left.");
    }
}                                      

public static double eval(char op, double val1, double val2)
{
    switch (op)
    {
        case '+':
            return val1 + val2;
        case '-':
            return val1 - val2;
        case '/':
            return val1 / val2;
        case '*':
            return val1 * val2;
        case '%':
            return val1 % val2;
        case 's':
            return Math.sqrt(val1);
        case 'l':
            return Math.log(val1);
        default:
            throw new RuntimeException("Operator is invalid.");
    }
}
```

To solve the `no delimiter` problem, I transform the string expression to a character array and iterate over it. At each step I:

- check if it is a valid operator
- if it is, add it to the stack
- if it is not, check if it is a valid digit
- if it is, check if it has more digits and build a string for that number
- if it is not, build the number

Comment: what if I have 100+40 how can i get each operand? i cant use charAt :/

Comment: If you use the shunting-yard algorithm you have 2 stacks. One for operands(the numbers) and one for operators(the signs).

Comment: I know.. but if I want to push the stack an operand, how can i get it without using charAt (maybe its 3 digits number) ?

Comment: I decided to post my implementation of the algorithm since it would be easier to understand than using a `Scanner.findInLine` with regular expressions to read the operators and operands XD

Comment: P.S: The first variant is also java-only. Java has integrated javascript engine.

Comment: If this answer was helpful don't forget to accept it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Javascript to evaluate the whole expression:

```
ScriptEngineManager manager = new ScriptEngineManager();
ScriptEngine engine = manager.getEngineByName("JavaScript");
String exp = "((2+100)*5)*7";
System.out.println(engine.eval(exp));
```

Comment: I need my own method (its kind of howmework to do). and I only allowed to use java methods

Answer (score 0):

A nice way to do this would be using some parser generator to create a parser of the input text. In java, there are several nice parsers. I would recommend using ANTLR, as the example you have provided is available in some of its basic tutorials. Some more details on that are on another question: [Parsing an arithmetic expression and building a tree from it in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4589951/parsing-an-arithmetic-expression-and-building-a-tree-from-it-in-java)

As pointed out, the accepted answer has a dead link. There are some variants of [Five minute introduction to ANTLR 3](https://theantlrguy.atlassian.net/wiki/display/ANTLR3/Five+minute+introduction+to+ANTLR+3) available