# Removing unnecessary/duplicates parentheses from arithmetic expressions using stack(s)

Tags: java, data-structures, stack

Write a program for finding duplicate parenthesis in a expression. 
For example :

```
(( a + b ) + (( c + d ))) = a + b + c + d
(( a + b ) * (( c + d ))) = (a + b) * (c + d)
```

One approach that I am aware of involves the following two steps:

1. Convert the given infix expression to postfix expression.
2. Convert back the postfix to infix

I don't want to do this entire process of converting from one representation to another, and then convert it back.

I want to do this using stack(s) but in a single pass. Is it possible ?

Please suggest an algorithm or share the code.

Comment: It's possible... depending on exactly how you define "a single pass".

Comment: By single pass, I mean traversing through the expression once.

Comment: What are the operations that you want to support? Only * - + / will do ?

Comment: The test expressions are too simple. I am not sure if it could be done in a single pass. For example, `((a+b/c) + ((d+e)) / (c) + (f+g)` results in an error because of missing closing parenthesis. I think you have to validate in one pass, and simplify on the next. But, I could be wrong. Do you also have to account for things like distributive property?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a [**recursive descent parser**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_descent_parser). This uses the function call stack implicitly, but not explicitly a Java stack. It can be implemented as follows:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(new Parser("(( a + b ) + (( c + d )))").parse());
        System.out.println(new Parser("(( a + b ) * (( c + d )))").parse());
    }
}

public class Parser {
    private final static char EOF = ';';
    private String input;
    private int currPos;

    public Parser(String input) {
        this.input = input + EOF; // mark the end
        this.currPos = -1;
    }

    public String parse() throws IllegalArgumentException {
        nextToken();
        Result result = expression();
        if(currToken() != EOF) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Found unexpected character '" + currToken() + "' at position " + currPos);
        }
        return result.getText();
    }

    // "expression()" handles "term" or "term + term" or "term - term"
    private Result expression() throws IllegalArgumentException {
        Result leftArg = term();

        char operator = currToken();
        if (operator != '+' && operator != '-') {
            return leftArg; // EXIT
        }
        nextToken();

        Result rightArg = term();

        if(operator == '-' && (rightArg.getOp() == '-' || rightArg.getOp() == '+')) {
            rightArg = encloseInParentheses(rightArg);
        }

        return new Result(leftArg.getText() + " " + operator + " " + rightArg.getText(), operator);
    }

    // "term()" handles "factor" or "factor * factor" or "factor / factor"
    private Result term() throws IllegalArgumentException {
        Result leftArg = factor();

        char operator = currToken();
        if (operator != '*' && operator != '/') {
            return leftArg; // EXIT
        }
        nextToken();

        Result rightArg = factor();

        if(leftArg.getOp() == '+' || leftArg.getOp() == '-') {
            leftArg = encloseInParentheses(leftArg);
        }
        if(rightArg.getOp() == '+' || rightArg.getOp() == '-' || (operator == '/' && (rightArg.getOp() == '/' || rightArg.getOp() == '*'))) {
            rightArg = encloseInParentheses(rightArg);
        }

        return new Result(leftArg.getText() + " " + operator + " " + rightArg.getText(), operator);
    }

    // "factor()" handles a "paren" or a "variable"
    private Result factor() throws IllegalArgumentException {
        Result result;
        if(currToken() == '(') {
            result = paren();
        } else if(Character.isLetter(currToken())) {
            result = variable();
        } else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Expected variable or '(', found '" + currToken() + "' at position " + currPos);
        }
        return result;
    }

    // "paren()" handles an "expression" enclosed in parentheses
    // Called with currToken an opening parenthesis
    private Result paren() throws IllegalArgumentException {
        nextToken();
        Result result = expression();
        if(currToken() != ')') {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Expected ')', found '" + currToken() + "' at position " + currPos);
        }
        nextToken();
        return result;
    }

    // "variable()" handles a variable
    // Called with currToken a variable
    private Result variable() throws IllegalArgumentException {
        Result result = new Result(Character.toString(currToken()), ' ');
        nextToken();
        return result;
    }

    private char currToken() {
        return input.charAt(currPos);
    }

    private void nextToken() {
        if(currPos >= input.length() - 1) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unexpected end of input");
        }
        do {
            ++currPos;
        }
        while(currToken() != EOF && currToken() == ' ');
    }

    private static Result encloseInParentheses(Result result) {
        return new Result("(" + result.getText() + ")", result.getOp());
    }

    private static class Result {
        private final String text;
        private final char op;

        private Result(String text, char op) {
            this.text = text;
            this.op = op;
        }

        public String getText() {
            return text;
        }

        public char getOp() {
            return op;
        }
    }
}
```

If you want to use an explicit stack, you could convert the algorithm from a recursive one to an iterative one, using a stack of something similar to the `Result` inner class. 
In fact, the Java compiler/JVM converts each recursive algorithm to a stack based one putting the local variables onto a stack.

But recursive decent parsers are easily readable by humans, hence I would prefer the solution presented above.

Answer (score 3):

If you only care about **duplicate** parentheses (as the question seems to imply), rather than those deemed necessary due to operator precedence (as the other answers seem to imply) you can indeed use a stack to keep track of which brackets you have encountered, and decide that any non-whitespace non-bracket characters **for each pair of parentheses** matters, which gives you a much simpler iterative traversal using a stack:

```
public class BracketFinder {

    public List<BracketPair> findUnnecessaryBrackets(String input) {
        List<BracketPair> unneccessaryBrackets = new LinkedList<BracketPair>();
        Deque<BracketPair> bracketStack = new LinkedBlockingDeque<BracketPair>();

        for (int cursor = 0; cursor < input.length(); cursor++ ) {
            if (input.charAt(cursor) == '(') {
                BracketPair pair = new BracketPair(cursor);
                bracketStack.addLast(pair);
            } else if (input.charAt(cursor) == ')') {
                BracketPair lastBracketPair = bracketStack.removeLast();
                lastBracketPair.end = cursor;
                if (!lastBracketPair.isNecessary) {
                    unneccessaryBrackets.add(lastBracketPair);
                }
            } else if (input.charAt(cursor) != ' ') {
                if (!bracketStack.isEmpty()) {
                    bracketStack.getLast().isNecessary = true;
                }
            }
        }

        return unneccessaryBrackets;
    }

    class BracketPair {
        public int start = -1;
        public int end = -1;
        public boolean isNecessary = false;

        public BracketPair(int startIndex) {
            this.start = startIndex;
        }
    }
}
```

Which you can test with the following

```
    public static void main(String... args) {
        List<BracketPair> results = new BracketFinder().findUnnecessaryBrackets("(( a + b ) + (( c + d ))) = a + b + c + d");
        for (BracketPair result : results) {
            System.out.println("Unneccessary brackets at indices " + result.start + "," + result.end);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Did not program it, but it could be look like this:

give the operations + / - the value 1
give the operations * & / the value 2
give the operation )( the value 2 (as its the same like *)

```
1 go to inner parenthesis and check if the next operation is higher in its value (means the parenthesis is necessary) or equal/lower to the own operation. if equal or lower the parenthesis is not necessary.

2 go to 1
```

you are finished, when there are no changes between 2 steps

hope this helped..
If you got an solution let me know please.
If this didn't help, let me know too :)

Greetings

Answer (score 1):

Its possible in one pass. The idea is to look for previous / next operation around each () block and apply associativity rules. Here is small table with yes/no marks when () is necessary.

```
        // (a + b) + c NO
        // (a + b) - c NO
        // (a + b) / c YES
        // (a + b) * c YES

        // (a / b) + c NO
        // (a / b) - c NO
        // (a / b) / c NO
        // (a / b) * c NO

        // a + (b + c) NO
        // a - (b + c) YES
        // a / (b + c) YES
        // a * (b + c) YES

        // a + (b / c) NO
        // a - (b / c) NO
        // a / (b / c) YES
        // a * (b / c) NO


        // (a) ((a))   NO
```

Here is C++ code (im not sure if its not missing some cases - its just an idea):

```
string clear(string expression)
{
    std::stack<int> openers;
    std::stack<int> closers;
    std::stack<bool> isJustClosed;
    std::stack<char> prevOperations;
    std::stack<bool> isComposite;
    std::stack<int> toDelete;


    prevOperations.push(' ');
    isJustClosed.push(false);
    isComposite.push(false);

    string result = expression + "@";
    for (int i = 0; i < result.length(); i++)
    {
        char ch = result[i];

        if ((ch == '*') || (ch == '/') || (ch == '+') || (ch == '-') || (ch == '(') || (ch == ')') || (ch == '@'))
            if (isJustClosed.size() > 0)
                if (isJustClosed.top() == true) {

                    // pop all and decide!
                    int opener = openers.top(); openers.pop();
                    int closer = closers.top(); closers.pop();
                    char prev = prevOperations.top(); prevOperations.pop();
                    char prevOperationBefore = prevOperations.top();
                    isJustClosed.pop(); //isJustClosed.push(false);
                    bool isComp = isComposite.top(); isComposite.pop();

                    bool ok = true;
                    if (prev == ' ')
                        ok = false;
                    else
                    {
                        ok = false;
                        if (((isComp) || (prev == '+') || (prev == '-')) && (ch == '/')) ok = true;
                        if (((isComp) || (prev == '+') || (prev == '-')) && (ch == '*')) ok = true;

                        if (((isComp) || (prev == '+') || (prev == '-')) && (prevOperationBefore == '-')) ok = true;
                        if (prevOperationBefore == '/') ok = true;
                        if (((isComp) || (prev == '+') || (prev == '-')) && (prevOperationBefore == '*')) ok = true;
                    }


                    if (!ok)
                    {
                        toDelete.push(opener);
                        toDelete.push(closer);
                    }
                }

        if (ch == '(') {
            openers.push(i);
            prevOperations.push(' ');
            isJustClosed.push(false);
            isComposite.push(false);
        }

        if (ch == ')') {
            closers.push(i);
            isJustClosed.top() = true;
        }

        if ((ch == '*') || (ch == '/') || (ch == '+') || (ch == '-')) {
            if (!isComposite.top())
            {
                char prev = prevOperations.top();
                if ((ch == '+') || (ch == '-'))
                    if ((prev == '*') || (prev == '/'))
                        isComposite.top() = true;
                if ((ch == '*') || (ch == '/'))
                    if ((prev == '+') || (prev == '-'))
                        isComposite.top() = true;
            }
            prevOperations.top() = ch;
            isJustClosed.top() = false;
        }


    }

    while (toDelete.size() > 0)
    {
        int pos = toDelete.top();
        toDelete.pop();
        result[pos] = ' ';
    }
    result.erase(result.size() - 1, 1);

    return result;
}
```

Inside each block we track last operation and also track if content is composite like (a+b*c).

Test:

```
void test()
    {
        LOG << clear("((a + (a + b))) - ((c)*(c) + d) * (b + d)") << NL;
        LOG << clear("a + (a + b) - ((c) + d) * (b + d)") << NL;
        LOG << clear("(a/b)*(c/d)") << NL;
        LOG << clear("(a/b)*((((c)/d)))") << NL;
        LOG << clear("((a + b) - (c - d))") << NL;
        LOG << clear("((a + b)*((c - d)))+c/d*((a*b))") << NL;
        LOG << clear("a+a*b*(a/b)") << NL;
        LOG << clear("a+a*b*(a+b)") << NL;
    }
```

Result:

```
  a +  a + b    - ( c * c  + d) *  b + d 
 a +  a + b  - ( c  + d) *  b + d 
a/b * c/d 
a/b *    c /d   
 a + b  - (c - d) 
(a + b)*  c - d   +c/d*  a*b  
a+a*b* a/b 
a+a*b*(a+b)
```

Answer (score 0):

Personally I think there are at least 2 ways:

- using a tree
- using [arithmetical polish notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polish_notation)

**Tree**

A tree can be created from the input expression. After the tree is created it can be flattened without the useless parentheses

- [Binary_expression_tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_expression_tree)
- [parsing-an-arithmetic-expression-and-building-a-tree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4589951/parsing-an-arithmetic-expression-and-building-a-tree-from-it-in-java)

**Polish notation**

- `(( a + b ) + (( c + d )))` will become `(+ (+ a b) (+ c d))`
- `(( a + b ) * (( c + d )))` will become `(* (+ a b) (+ c d))`

From here you could compare the each operand and the factors to see if they have the same priority in solving the arithmetical equation

I would go with the tree.