# Java. How to evaluate a String expression?

Tags: java

I have a mathematical expression in the form of a String. 
`String exp = "3 + 6 - 10 + 12 + 15";` 
Now how to calculate the result of this expression as we do with other mathematical expressions. 
Help me.

Comment: you must translate your string in numbers and operators. There is no function for it afaik. Edit: Maybe Script- Engine: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3422673/evaluating-a-math-expression-given-in-string-form

Comment: Check out [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4589951/2032064)

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that there may only be `+` and `-` operations, you can remove all the whitespaces and split it to positive and negative integers and sum them.

```
String expr = "3 + 6 - 10 + 12 + 15";
String[] nums = expr.replaceAll("\\s", "").split("\\+|(?=-)");
int result = Arrays.stream(nums).mapToInt(Integer::parseInt).sum();
```

If the expressions can be more complex though, including more operators or parentheses, you have to use another solution.

Comment: This solution is far better than the script engine.

Answer (score 0):

You can use BeanShell bsh.Interpreter for the same:

```
Interpreter interpreter = new Interpreter(); 
interpreter.eval("result = 5+4*(7-15)");
System.out.println(interpreter.get("result"));
```

It will evaluate complex mathematical expression.

Answer (score -1):

Through JDK 1.6 or Higher.

```
    ScriptEngineManager mgr = new ScriptEngineManager();
    ScriptEngine engine = mgr.getEngineByName("JavaScript");
    String expression = "3+6-10+12+15";
    try {
        System.out.println(engine.eval(expression));
    } catch (ScriptException ex) {
        System.out.println("Error occured.");
    }
```

Comment: This is prone to [code injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_injection)... what if this value is taken from user input and they write `txt = "a";while(1){txt = txt += "a";}`? That will crash you. Also, malicious programs could potentially be run. Using Javascript just to calculate some basic arithmetic seems a bit hardcore, anyway.