# String.split() returns an array with an additional empty value

Tags: java, regex, string, spring-el

I'm working on a piece of code where I've to split a string into individual parts. **The basic logic flow of my code is, the numbers below on the LHS, i.e 1, 2 and 3 are ids of an object. Once I split them, I'd use these ids, get the respective value and replace the ids in the below String with its respective values.** The string that I have is as follow -

```
String str = "(1+2+3)>100";
```

I've used the following code for splitting the string -

```
String[] arraySplit = str.split("\\>|\\<|\\=");
String[] finalArray = arraySplit[0].split("\\(|\\)|\\+|\\-|\\*");
```

Now the arrays that I get are as such -

```
arraySplit = [(1+2+3), >100];
finalArray = [, 1, 2, 3];
```

So, after the string is split, I'd replace the string with the values, i.e the string would now be, `(20+45+50)>100` where 20, 45 and 50 are the respective values. *(this string would then be used in SpEL to evaluate the formula)*

I'm almost there, just that I'm getting an empty element at the first position. **Is there a way to not get the empty element in the second array, i.e `finalArray`?** Doing some research on this, I'm guessing it is splitting the string `(1+2+3)` and taking an empty element as a part of the string. 
If this is the thing, then **is there any other method apart from `String.split()` that would give me the same result?**

Edit -

Here, `(1+2+3)>100` is just an example. The round braces are part of a formula, and the string could also be as `((1+2+3)*(5-2))>100`.

Edit 2 -

After splitting this String and doing some code over it, I'm goind to use this string in **SpEL**. So **if there's a better solution by directly using SpEL then also it would be great.**

Also, currently I'm using the syntax of the formula as such - **(1+2+3) * 4>100** but if there's a way out by changing the formula syntax a bit then that would also be helpful, e.g replacing the formula by - **({#1}+{#2}+{#3}) *
 {#4}>100**, in this case I'd get the variable using {# as the variable and get the numbers.

I hope this part is clear.

Edit 3 -

Just in case, **SpEL is also there in my project *although I don't have much idea on it*, so if there's a better solution using SpEL then its more than welcome**. The basic logic of the question is written at the starting of the question in bold.

Comment: @DavidArenburg yeah, I'm using Java

Comment: Show a complex example along with what you expect to get as output.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen hey, I've updated the question with my code logic and an example. Kindly have a look.

Comment: You still haven't told us what you are trying to do here.  If you want to parse a nested algebraic expression, regex is probably a poor choice.  Instead, you'd likely want a parser of some kind.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen here's a brief idea - 
I'd be having a string containing a formula that would be having some IDs in the LHS *(1,2,3 in the upper case)*. This string is then split to get an array of the IDs. Later, these IDs are replaced in the string with the respective readings *(30,45,50 in the upper case)*. This replaced string is then used in SpEL to get the value of the formula. So the string needs to be tranformed from *(1+2+3)>100* to *(30.0+45.0+50.0)>100*.

Hope this clears up some confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you take a look at the [split(String regex, int limit)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-int-)<sup>(emphasis is mine)</sup>:

> When there is a positive-width match at the beginning of this string then an empty leading substring is included at the beginning of the resulting array.

Thus, you can specify `0` as `limit` param:

> **If n is zero** then the pattern will be applied as many times as possible, the array can have any length, and **trailing empty strings will be discarded**.

Comment: hey, @thomas this might be helpful in my case and I'll give it a try but this solves half of my problem. I still have an issue while replacing the string with the readings. Kindly have a look at the edited question.

Comment: @Trivedi the original question is *String.split() returns an array with an additional empty value*. If you encounter issue while replacing thoses values we'll need to take a look at the code you wrote and that is not in the scope of this question: you should ask another one :)

Comment: Well then could you help me out in the second part of the question, I'll edit the title of the question. Asking a new question won't be a good idea as both of these issues have a same work case and code behind it. Hope you understand my viewpoint here. :)

Comment: @Trivedi please read [One post with multiple questions or multiple posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39223/one-post-with-multiple-questions-or-multiple-posts). I'll be glad to help you with another question

Comment: hey here's the link to the separate question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43720022/string-replace-returns-unwanted-string

Answer (score 1):

If you keep things really simple, you may be able to get away with using a combination of regular expressions and string operations like split and replace.

However, it looks to me like you'd be better off writing a simple parser using ANTLR.

Take a look at [Parsing an arithmetic expression and building a tree from it in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4589951/parsing-an-arithmetic-expression-and-building-a-tree-from-it-in-java) and https://theantlrguy.atlassian.net/wiki/display/ANTLR3/Five+minute+introduction+to+ANTLR+3

Edit: I haven't used ANTLR in a while - it's now up to version 4, and there may be some significant differences, so make sure that you check the documentation for that version.