# String.replace() returns unwanted string

Tags: java, string, replace, spring-el

I'm working on a piece of code where I've to split a string into individual parts and replace them. **The basic logic flow of my code is, there's a string that contains a formula. The numbers below on the LHS, i.e 1, 2 and 3 are ids of different objects. Once I split them, I'd use these ids, get the respective value and replace the ids in the below String with its respective values.** The string that I have is as follow -

```
String str = "(1+2+3)>100";
```

I've used the following code for splitting the string -

```
String[] arraySplit = str.split("\\>|\\<|\\=");
String[] finalArray = arraySplit[0].split("\\(|\\)|\\+|\\-|\\*");
arraySplit[0] = arraySplit[0].replace(id,reading);
```

So, after the string is split, I'd replace the string with the values, i.e the string would now be, `(30+45+50)>100` where 30, 45 and 50 are the respective values. *(this string would then be used in SpEL to evaluate the formula)*

While replacing the string with the values, I'm getting the following response -

Initial string -

`(1+2+3)>100` where 1, 2 and 3 are ids. Respective values of the ids are 30.0, 45.0 and 50.0.

After replacing the value *by using a for loop*, the string is -

`(50.00.0+45.0+50.0)>100`. The first value is quite weird. The reason for this is while in the third iteration, the string looked like this - (30.0+45.0+3)>100. So while replacing the string in the third iteration, it **replaces all instances of 3 with 50.0** hence resulting in the above string. So apparently using `String.replace()` won't be a better option here. What method should I use in this case then? I'm also using SpEL, so if there's a better solution to this using SpEL then also its good.

Here, `(1+2+3)>100` is just an example. The round braces are part of a formula, and the string could also be as `((1+2+3)*(5-2))>100`. Or even the syntax of the formula could be changed, currently the formula is as such - **(1+2+3) * 4>100** but if there's a way out by changing the formula syntax a bit then that would also be helpful, e.g replacing the formula by - **({#1}+{#2}+{#3}) *
 {#4}>100**, in this case I'd get the variable using {# as the variable and get the numbers.

I hope this part is clear.

Comment: One way would be to first replace ids with a letter (ex: A for 1, B for 2) and replace in two steps instead of one single

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're right, `String.replace` is not the right tool for the job here.

What you want to do is to *tokenize* the input string, then operate on the tokens. Optionally you can combine back into a string at the end, but it depends on what you intend to do with the formula.

For example, you want to tokenize the string `"(1+2+3)>100"` into the array `["(", "1", "+", "2", "+", "3", ")", ">", "100"]`. This is simply a matter of splitting on every boundary between a digit and a symbol.

From this representation, it's a simple matter to replace the entire tokens in the array with their corresponding values, e.g. find the array index that has value `"1"` and replace it with `"30.0"`, etc. Then you can create a new expression string by just joining all the parts in the array back together.

If you want to go one step further, you can translate into an *expression tree*, which would look something like this:

```
OpGreaterThan
    OpPlus
        Symbol(1)
        OpPlus
            Symbol(2)
            Symbol(3)
    Literal(100)
```

This tree is formed by transforming the input expression (which is rendered in standard infix notation) into reverse polish notation, then building a tree where each node is an operator and its children are operands. This would allow you to symbolically manipulate and/or evaluate the formula.