# Not expression conversion but conversion from preorder to Inorder (not expression)

Tags: c++, binary-search-tree

I am not asking for a expression conversion

[conversion from infix to prefix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1946896/conversion-from-infix-to-prefix)

I am just asking that for a BST, if the input is given in the form of prefix notation, i.e,preorder traversal of BST, Then how do i convert the sequence of values to infix notation, i.e Inorder traversal of a BST.

```
                 8
               /  \
              1    12
              \     /
               5   9
             /   \
            4     7
                 /
                6
```

for example the preorder traversal would give   8 1 5 4 7 6 12 9

how do i convert these sequence of values(inputs) 
to a inorder traversal expression 1 4 5 6 7 8 9 12.

AS in some cases inorder expression is easier to handle...

Comment: "I am not asking for a expression conversion" - um, you are.

Comment: I would expect the pre-order traversal to be: 1 4 5 6 7 8 9 12, using 'left subtree, node, right subtree`.

Answer (score 0):

With a BST:
**Prefix**: Left subtree, node, right subtree.
**Infix**: Node, left subtree, right subtree.
**Postfix**: right subtree, left subtree, node.

The conversion depends on how you traverse the tree.

Comment: I know that but i just wanted to know , if a sequence is given in prorder form , how do i convert the sequence of values into inorder form.

Comment: Put it into a sorted BST, with left-most leaf containing the first node and the right-most leaf containing the maximum value.  Then traverse it.  Otherwise re-order the nodes (organizing into a new tree often helps vs. inplace re-ordering).

Comment: For your application, you should not tailor the tree to pre-order, but something more generic.

Comment: BSTs can be in any order.  Sorted BSTs can produce different results by how you traverse them.  Take a pen and paper and try the different methods I posted.  When "node" is encountered, write the number.

Answer (score 0):

Let

V = Vertex

L = Left Subtree

R = Right Subtree

Preorder = VLR

Inorder = LVR

Postorder = LRV

(Just switch order to fix and it's the same)

One way to put them back to make prefix values to infix values is to create a Binary Search Tree again with prefix values and do the Inorder traversal.

OR!

Just sort dude... (BST is always sorted if u squash them to a line (squash from top to bottom))